# VMware with bridged network and DHCPs

Tags: vmware, dhcp, ip

In our office we use VMware for almost everything. Our host machine is pretty empty and we just use it to run the Workstation. From time to time we copy one machine to other coworker and then we have the issue that the office DHCP gives the same IP to both machines (we say to the Workstation that the machine has been copied, not moved).

I suppose that this behavior is because the MAC is the same in both machines.

Is there a way of changing it or fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first time you open a freshly copied virtual machine VMWare usually asks you the question:

> Did you move or copy this virtual
>   machine?

If you select copy it will change the MAC address.
I know this is true for VMWare 6.5 and up, don't know about older versions.

You can change the MAC address manually by editing the vmx file in a text editor

it looks something like this:

ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:27:7c:f5"

Comment: We always select "I copied", anyway I already found the way to change the MAC, is something harder than changing the generatedAddress. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That's it, all the vmware copyies has the same information, when you copy it and open it for the first time,there should be an option: did you move it or copy it? If you choose copy, then the problems come. You can change the mac address manually.

Comment: How can I change the mac address? I've not seen the option at the network settings